# What does “his A and C” mean?

Tags: meaning

From Steinbeck's *Cannery Row*,

> The nice bouncer at the Bear Flag threw out a drunk, but threw him too hard and too far and broke his back. Alfred had to go over to Salinas three times before it was cleared up and that didn’t make Alfred feel very well. Ordinarily he was too good a bouncer to hurt anyone. **His A and C was a miracle of rhythm and grace.**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It refers to [*arse and collar*](http://science.niuz.biz/and-t16074.html?s=6ad3da250bb4239bc6a1c5a6fe5c15a6&) (or [*ass and collar*](http://www.steinbeckbibliography.org/drupal/?q=node/56298)), a technique whereby a bouncer hoists an offending patron from the rear of the belt or waist of the pants and collar of the shirt in order to propel him in a certain direction, usually out the door.

Comment: Also known as *the bum's rush*.

Comment: Never heard either term before. Wonderful!